# Java Re-Initialize primitive array on 1 line

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, primitive

I like the shorthand of initializing arrays on 1 line

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
```

But sometimes I want to change all the values in the array, but this throws an error

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
array = {10,20,30};     //Error: "Array constants can only be used in initializers"
```

So my hack is to make a temporary array & set the 1st equal the the temporary array

```
int[] array = {1,2,3};
int[] tempArray = {10,20,30};
array = tempArray;
```

Is there a better way to do this without creating an extra array?

Comment: you could loop the current array and multiply the values by 10?

Comment: How is `int[] tempArray = {10,20,30}; array = tempArray;` better than `array = new int[] {10,20,30};`? Not only you have to type more code but also it takes 2 lines instead of 1...

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I didn't say it was better, in fact I was trying to avoid this because it's more code.
But thanks for the `array = new int[] {10,20,30};` trick.

I just noticed it's flagged as a duplicate so I can read that post